# Approach for researching developers using SDKs and APIs

Tags: api

We do enteprise software and we have a couple of projects coming up where we're building Software Development Kits and APIs that will be used by developers in our customers' IT departments.

When it comes to learning about the needs of developers and evaluating their use of our SDKs and APIs, does anyone have any examples they can share of approaches they've found to be effective?

I'm thinking of doing some contextual interviews for discovering needs and then possibly a diary study for evaluating usage of pre-release versions of the SDKs and APIs.

Any other thoughts?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Contextual inquiry is a good idea, as well as just doing some straight-up interviews with your representative developers to learn about their use cases, workflows, etc. You could also do some exploration into results of research that OTHERS have done. It may take some searching, but you'll find some guidance:

- http://doc.utwente.nl/89586/
- https://www.quora.com/What-do-developers-who-use-APIs-want-from-their-platform-or-SDK

Also, the developer forums for different products might provide some insights:

- https://docs.brightcove.com/en/perform/mobile-sdks/forum/sdk.html
- https://developers.google.com/drive/
- https://developer.spotify.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to devil advocate the usage of interviews. We tried this method , but generally it fails due to unknown unknowns. Most developers that we interviewed have no idea what to even ask or complain. At first, we thought the product was close to perfect.

However, we decided to go with another approach. We monitored the use directly, by analysing step-by-step implementation. We handed out a checklist that contains, some of the docs, and implementation methods, and we make them check a box for each step and write a short remark if needed.

We realised developers are MacGyvers. They use the product, no problems, but have an agreed solution to bugs, and usability among themselves. They don't raise the issue during the interviews because they assume that "correcting" such bugs, is part of using the product, which is clearly not.

In the following months, we were able to fix all the issues and the workflow improved tremendously. Previously DIY solutions became options or new features.

Comment: I have had success with interviews with developers... Just like creating tasks for a usability test, however, you have to create your questions carefully. You can't just ask them "What do you want?", you need to come at it from other angles: "What are your biggest challenges?" "Tell me about your process/workflow/dev environment." That sort of thing. Agreed, if you can watch them at workin their home environment that can be best. We don't always (read: ever) have that option... But an interview we can do by phone.